# Given a two-digit integer, swap its digits and print the result python

Tags: python, swap

Is there a way to swap the digits of a 2-digit integer without converting to string and back?

```
number = int(input())

digit_1 = number // 10
digit_2 = number % 10
swapped_number = (digit_2 * 10)+ digit_1
print(swapped_number)
```

so this is what i have so far and it works beside for the fact that 10 will be outputed to just 1 instead of 01 any ideas? This also happens with any tens numbers with a 0 in it like 20 50 ect, it just takes out the 0

I tried changing the % and //

Comment: This is not a duplicate. OP wants to print leading zeros too.

Comment: What type would the 01 be? int? and do you only want to print it? Why is it not allowed to convert to string?

Comment: @Pierre You've put words into OP's mouth. If they're given a two-digit integer *as string input*, then there's little reason to look for any solutions besides a string reversal.

Comment: @deceze: fair enough. That's the only thing I could think of that would make the question interesting. In the title it says "two-digit integer", so that was my frame of mind there. But then they get the number from `int(input())`. Shrug.

Comment: @wim: fun puzzle -- reminds me of "Hacker's delights" (one of my favorite books). One twist compared to my initial comment was that simply `(10 * x) % 99` was correct except for `x = 99`. That's why in the answer below I used `(10 * x - 1) % 99 + 1` instead. Less satisfying, but now correct for `1 <= x < 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the integer to string. Then you can swap it like so:

```
number = input()
print(number[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment:

To reverse the digits of a 2-digit integer (assuming `10 <= x < 100`):

```py
y = (10 * x - 1) % 99 + 1
```

To print a leading 0:

```py
f'{x:02d}'
```

##### Verification

```py
for x in range(1, 100):
    truth = int(f'{x:02d}'[::-1])
    y = (10 * x - 1) % 99 + 1
    assert y == truth
```

Note: single-digit integers work as well, as long as they are `x > 0`: for `x` in `[1,2,3,...]` we get `y = [10,20,30,...]`.

Answer (score 0):

number = int(input())

left = int(number / 10)
right = (number % 10)

print(str(left) + "" + str(right))

found the solution this ended up working thanks, everyone for your responses!